# Laravel php-FFMpeg x264 error

Tags: laravel, ffmpeg, laravel-5, x264, ffmpeg-php

I installed FFMpeg for Ubuntu and php-FFMpeg for Laravel with composer.
All worked great as long I take the format wmv or webm. 
If i take x264 to convert a video to mp4 i get two error messages.
 
First this one:

```
RuntimeException in Video.php line 168:
Encoding failed
```

and:

```
ExecutionFailureException in ProcessRunner.php line 100:
ffmpeg failed to execute command '/usr/bin/ffmpeg' '-y' '-i' 'video/Wildlife.wmv' '-vcodec' 'libx264' '-acodec' 'libfaac' '-b:v' '1000k' '-refs' '6' '-coder' '1' '-sc_threshold' '40' '-flags' '+loop' '-me_range' '16' '-subq' '7' '-i_qfactor' '0.71' '-qcomp' '0.6' '-qdiff' '4' '-trellis' '1' '-b:a' '128k' '-pass' '1' '-passlogfile' '/tmp/ffmpeg-passes573ed5409ca54kgxj2/pass-573ed5409cad7' 'video/export-x264.mp4'
```

and this is my ffmpeg configuration

```
configuration: --extra-libs=-ldl --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --mandir=/usr/share/man --enable-avresample --disable-debug --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --disable-decoder=amrnb --disable-decoder=amrwb --enable-libpulse --enable-libfreetype --enable-gnutls --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libvorbis --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvpx --enable-libspeex --enable-libass --enable-avisynth --enable-libsoxr --enable-libxvid --enable-libvidstab
```

Comment: Could you provide the full stack trace of the error?
Have you tried to copy the command and to execute it manually? '/usr/bin/ffmpeg' '-y' '-i' 'video/Wildlife.wmv' '-vcodec' 'libx264' '-acodec' 'libfaac' '-b:v' '1000k' '-refs' '6' '-coder' '1' '-sc_threshold' '40' '-flags' '+loop' '-me_range' '16' '-subq' '7' '-i_qfactor' '0.71' '-qcomp' '0.6' '-qdiff' '4' '-trellis' '1' '-b:a' '128k' '-pass' '1' '-passlogfile' '/tmp/ffmpeg-passes573ed5409ca54kgxj2/pass-573ed5409cad7' 'video/export-x264.mp4' Thanks
Romain

Comment: Did you try to execute the command without the single quotes?